# GetStream Additional User Properties

Tags: flutter, getstream-io

i am using stream sdk for my chat application. i am trying to add additional properties to further describe my user, however, there isn’t any documentation on how i could achieve that. any ideas? tia

“There are additional properties you can provide to further describe your users.” from https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/update_users/?language=dart

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom properties to user using the `extraData` property of the `User` class.

`extradata` is a `Map<String, Object?>`

Example:

```dart
final user = User(id: "john", extraData: {
  "name": "John Doe",
  "custom_property": 10,
});

client.updateUser(User); //to update the user in the backend
```

Comment: oh thank you so much! but how do i then retrieve this data later on? below is how i am displaying the name on another screen.

```
Hero(
              tag: 'hero-profile-picture',
              child: Avatar.large(url: user?.image),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(user?.name ?? 'No name'),
            ),
```

Comment: This is correct

Comment: In the example I posted you could do `user.extraData['custom_property]` to retrieve the custom property value

Comment: its saying 'The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.'

Answer (score 0):

ive managed to retrieve the data with this

```
user?.extraData['designation'] as String
```

hope this will help anyone along the way